# Rotating an Image in java

Tags: java, graphics

I have an image of a Pan Card and when I try to rotate it by 45 degrees and save it, I get a cropped image.
Code to rotate an image is:

```
    BufferedImage dimg = new BufferedImage(w, h, img.getType());
    Graphics2D g = dimg.createGraphics();
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, // Anti-alias!
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    g.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle), w / 2, h / 2);

    g.drawImage(img, null, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687926/how-can-i-rotate-an-image-using-java-swing-and-then-set-its-origin-to-0-0

Comment: one more thing guys i want to include some functionality such as zooming, cropping, in my project can get any utility jar for my project...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at [this example](http://www.billthelizard.blogspot.com/2008/07/rotate-image-in-java.html), using AffineTransform.

There's some code to load the image, then this is the core:

```
private Image image;
AffineTransform identity = new AffineTransform();

Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
AffineTransform trans = new AffineTransform();
trans.setTransform(identity);
trans.rotate( Math.toRadians(45) );
g2d.drawImage(image, trans, this);
```

Comment: how do you position the transformed image? drawImage method does not seem to have a constructor for that