# Rotation of an image in Java

Tags: java, android

After rotating an image I have a problem like this. The image is partially cut and not displaying as expected.

**Before rotating:**

[image]

**After rotating:**

[image]

I am using this code for rotation:

```
AffineTransform tx = new AffineTransform();
tx.rotate(Math.toRadians(61), image.getWidth() / 2, image.getHeight() / 2);

AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(
                         tx, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
image = op.filter(image, null);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10685016/rotating-an-image-in-java

Comment: What is wrong with the result? What is your desired outcome?

Comment: @TCPN you use CSS in Translation Effect .

Comment: I need full image. Do you see image after rotate it not the same.

Comment: @AshishShahi what is it?

Comment: Did you try the set bigger frame size ?

Comment: @Oguz I didn't try yet.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ What is (Graphic2D) g? i don't have this variable.

Comment: The rectangle is being clipped to a view area. Since you are asking this question, I assume that the top of your screenshot here is not the top of the device's screen. Is that correct? Can you show another screenshot that indicates the entire screen size?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this as your style:

```
 App-logo { animation: App-logo-spin infinite 20s linear;}
```